# Transfert output from docker container to host's focused window

Tags: docker, unix

I have a C# app running on a container, on the host i have a web page with simple fields. When the app receives data, I want it to fill up the focused field with it.

I can use the C# app with [Control.KeyPress](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), but the result won't escape the container.

First idea I have is to simulate keypresses for the host, by having a script run on the host that uses `xdotool` to simulate keypresses, but the problem is that is undermining the docker usefulness, and is only working for hosts with unix runining, `xdotool` installed and the script runining in the background, not even talking about security...

Maybe I can mount some volumes and write the data directly somewhere, but i don't know where.

The host is always going to be an Unix system, but the version and packages can change.
Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1-alpine

COPY ./publish MyApp/

ENTRYPOINT dotnet MyApp/MyApp.dll
```

Is there a way to directly output data from a container?

Comment: "Talking about security": a tool that can directly manipulate the keyboard is a huge problem.  The most common way to interact with a Docker container is probably to run an HTTP service as the main container process and then use a tool like `curl` to make requests to it; will this work for you?

Comment: @DavidMaze i have no control on the main web page, thats why i want to "fill" the fields using another way ...